# Saturated versus all other fats

Tags: muscle, strength, diet, muscle-gain, maintenance

You mention "fat" often and as a collective value; but isn't there a big difference between saturated and all the others (Unsat, Mono, Poly, Etc), in terms of metabolism and what is used toward building or maintaining?  What's the general rule of avoidance, by ratio?
Subject is a 19yr old male (5' 11", 150 lbs) who just started working out in a gym regularly.
Thank you

Comment: Hi! Questions that are primarily focused on nutrition are off topic here. Meanwhile, there is a Biology site that might me more suited to the question. Make sure to read the respective Help Center of the site you're about to post to to get an overview of what's on and off topic.